# Python dateutil: AttributeError: module 'dateutil' has no attribute 'parse'

Tags: python-3.x, date, parsing

Trying to use dateutil to parse dates from an unknown format but none of the documented methods are found?

CODE:

```
import dateutil
print(dateutil.parser.parse("24.05.2017"))
exit(1)
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(dateutil.parser.parse("24.05.2017"))
AttributeError: module 'dateutil' has no attribute 'parser'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can fix this error by modifying your code slightly:

```
from dateutil import parser
print(parser.parse("24.05.2017"))
```

This change is needed because of how the dateutil package internally organizes it's modules.

Comment: @Gunther, you method works for python3, could you explain a little bit?

Answer (score 11):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, the dotted notation is still valid if you change the import:

```
import dateutil.parser
print(dateutil.parser.parse("24.05.2017"))
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked while the accepted answer didn't.